# invalid column type getint not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.t4CRowidAccessor hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I am using this
http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/21/spring-3-and-hibernate-integration-tutorial-with-example/

tutorial to create a Spring + Hibernate App.But I am getting this exception while inserting data. I am using Oracle.

```
Could not insert : howtodoinjava.entity.EmployeeEntity

invalid column type getInt not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.t4CRowidAccessor
```

Where in the program I am using getInt ?

EmployeeDaoImpl.java

```
package com.howtodoinjava.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.howtodoinjava.entity.EmployeeEntity;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDAO
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Override
    public void addEmployee(EmployeeEntity employee) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(employee);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<EmployeeEntity> getAllEmployees() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from EmployeeEntity").list();
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(Integer employeeId) {
        EmployeeEntity employee = (EmployeeEntity) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                EmployeeEntity.class, employeeId);
        if (null != employee) {
            this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

EmployeeEntity.java

```
package com.howtodoinjava.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeEntity 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="TELEPHONE")
    private String telephone;

public void setid(int id)
{
  this.id = id;
}
public int getid()
{
  return id;
}

public void setfirstname(String firstname)
{
  this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getfirstname()
{
  return firstname;
}

public void setlastname(String lastname)
{
  this.lastname = lastname;
}
public String getlastname()
{
  return lastname;
}

public void setemail(String email)
{
  this.email = email;
}
public String getemail()
{
  return email;
}
public void settelephone(String telephone)
{
  this.telephone = telephone;
}
public String gettelephone()
{
  return telephone;
}

}
```

Comment: Post code of your entity and dao

Comment: Please post the stacktrace. It looks like this is falling foul of the Oracle JDBC driver returning the ROW_ID from `getGeneratedKeys` and not the generated id.

Answer (score 0):

you can alternatively refer to this tutorial

http://www.ekiras.com/2015/02/maven-spring-mvc-hibernate-sitemesh-hello-world-project.html

What i think you might be missing is the getters and setters for the class, due to which it will not be able to set the values for the class variables.

Comment: I added the getters & setters as well.

Comment: The hibernate takes the ID as  Long datatype and not the integer type. Please try making it as Long.

Comment: I have used `private Long id`, Error `invalid column type getLong not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.t4CRowidAccessor`

Comment: ok, did you create the getter setters on your own ? i mean u have mentioned the getter setter as, getid() however it should have been getId() and setId(),

Comment: Yes, I have created my own getters & setters. With getId() and setId(), it was creating problem with `messages_en.properties` file labels.

Comment: Hibernate will always search for getters and setter in the format `get` then field name in camelcase like for `userName` if will search `getUserName`. the other problem u mentioned can be fixed but this cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can resolve it.

replace **Integer** with **int** in your EmployeeEntity.java

or by changing generated annotation as below in EmployeeEntity.java

```
@Id 
@Column(name="ID", unique = true, nullable = false) 
@**GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)**
```